# knockout observable array binding to view when there is a delay in assigning value not happening

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a knockout observable array whose value assignment changes after a set value of time but do not see this reflecting in the view. Could someone tell where I am doing it wrong? I would expect the output to show

•   GRE 1111
•   TOEFL 111

but it shows

•   GRE2 222
•   TOEFL2 22

jsFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/4r37x9y5/

HTML:

```js
console.clear();

function viewModel() { 

this.plans = ko.observableArray([]);
    
    var plans1 = [
        { id: 'GRE', count: '1111' },
        { id: 'TOEFL', count: '111' },
        ];
        
            var plans2 = [
        { id: 'GRE2', count: '222' },
        { id: 'TOEFL2', count: '22' },
        ];
        
        this.plans = plans2;
        //this.plans = plans1;
        
        setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("In timeout before assigning plans");
      this.plans = plans1;
      console.log(this.plans);
      }, 2000);     

}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel());
// The above line equals:
// viewModel(); // updates window object and returns null!
// ko.applyBindings(); // binds window object to body!
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: plans" class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <span data-bind="text: id"></span>
            <span data-bind="text: count"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of issues here. As mentioned by you in the comments, you are not binding an object with observables. You are simply adding a global variable `plans`. If knockout can't find a property in the viewModel, it will use the window object's property. That's why it works the first time

- You need to change `viewModel` as a constructor function and use `new viewModel()` to create an object or an instance.
- observables should be [read and updated](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#reading-and-writing-observables) by calling them as functions. So, `this.plans(plans1)`. If you set `this.plans = plans2`, it will simply overwrite the observable with a simple array without the subscribers to update the UI when the property changes
- You need to use [correct `this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) inside `setTimeout`. Either by creating a `self = this` variable outside or using an arrow function as a callback

```js
function viewModel() {
  this.plans = ko.observableArray([]);
  
  var plans1 = [{ id: "GRE", count: "1" }, { id: "TOEFL", count: "1" }];
  var plans2 = [{ id: "GRE2", count: "2" }, { id: "TOEFL2", count: "2" }];

  this.plans(plans2) // call it like a function

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("In timeout before assigning plans");
    this.plans(plans1)
  }, 2000);
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel()); // new keyword to create an object
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: plans">
  <li>
    <span data-bind="text: id"></span>
    <span data-bind="text: count"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```